# ./install: function: not found - gpu-blast

Tags: shell, ubuntu-14.04, bioinformatics, blast

I'm trying install gpu-blast (http://archimedes.cheme.cmu.edu/?q=gpublast) on my ubuntu 14.04 and have this issue:

```
mar@mar-Lenovo-ideapad-Y700-15ISK:~/blast$ sh ./install 
install: 6: install: function: not found
-ne .
-ne .
-ne .
-ne .
-ne .
-ne .
```

I do option 2 from here: http://thales.cheme.cmu.edu/gpublast/README
I've tried with sudo and chmod but result is the same.

Comment: `function` is not standard POSIX sh syntax; scripts that use it should not be invoked with `sh`.

Comment: ...which is to say that it looks like you found a bug in gpublast's README, insofar as it instructs using `sh` to run a script that isn't actually compliant with the POSIX sh standard.

Answer (score 0):

The install script is a bash script? (Don't have a Ubuntu system, but if I recall the sh in Ubuntu is actually just a symlink dash not bash), try bash ./install

Comment: Insofar as bash honors the function keyword when invoked under the name `sh`, that's a place where its POSIX compatibility mode is needlessly permissive.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that sh on his system is not bash but completely different implementation (on debian (which I think ubuntu is based on) the /bin/sh is actually dash, not bash. But as said I do not have ubuntu system at hand so I cannot verify this).

Comment: Yes, I agree, but my point is that it's **never** safe to assume that `sh` supports features not present in the POSIX sh standard, no matter if it's provided by dash or ash or ksh or posh or mksh or zsh or any other shell. Even if it *were* bash, a future version of bash would be within its specification to be more faithful to the letter of the POSIX sh standard and disallow the `function` keyword when running in POSIX compatibility mode.

Comment: ...so telling people to think of this as an Ubuntu problem or a dash problem is a bit misguided -- the place where there's a bug is where the gpublast README instructs someone to use `sh` to run a script they provide that relies on non-POSIX-specified syntax.

Comment: (...just to be sure it's clear, so my prior comments can be read in context, starting bash under the name `sh` enables POSIX compatibility mode, with all the differences documented at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html; while current releases of bash still *allow* function declarations using the `function` keyword in that mode -- and, to be fair, will probably continue to do so in the future -- you'll note that when in that mode they *emit* a serialization of defined functions in POSIX-compatible format, with no `function` keyword preceding).